# Need assistance with external CSS reference

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn how to use Cascadding Style Sheets.    I have a little test html page as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <h3> A White Header </h3>
     <p> This paragraph has a blue font.  
      The background color of this page is gray because
   we changed it with CSS! </p>
  <INPUT TYPE=text NAME="userID" id="userID" Size=20 > 
</body>
```

And the external css file looks like this:

```
body{ background-color: gray;} 
 p { color: blue; } 
h3{ color: white; }
```

This all works fine.   But when I look at style sheets created by other members of my team, they have style tags bracketing the content.   So it makes me think that the CSS file really should look like this:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
body{ background-color: gray;} 
p { color: blue; } 
h3{ color: white; }


</style>
```

However, when I put the style tag in disables the CSS.   What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Ellliott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<style>` HTML tag is for when your CSS is *in* your HTML file.

If it's an external CSS file, you do not use them, as it's not an HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

The `<style>` tag is an [HTML tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2) that you can use to include CSS directly in the page. An external CSS file should just contain the CSS declarations, and not be wrapped in HTML.

For example (taking your HTML):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> <!-- style is an HTML element -->
    body { background-color: gray; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <h3> A White Header </h3>
     <p> This paragraph has a blue font.  
      The background color of this page is gray because
   we changed it with CSS! </p>
  <INPUT TYPE=text NAME="userID" id="userID" Size=20 > 
</body>
```

According to the HTML spec, your method is best:

> To specify style information for more than one element, authors should
>   use the STYLE element. For optimal flexibility, authors should define
>   styles in external style sheets.